# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments. Receiver:

Tags: android, flutter, http

this Model

[image: 1]

saya ingin menampilkan data dengam mengambil dari framework saya

Comment: i want to display data by fetching from my framework

Comment: this Myprovider

Future<ProfilModel> fetchProfil() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(
      'http://172.22.15.10/efindings_api/public/user/profil/accef7258468a53084f2466fc2502969',
    ),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return ProfilModel.fromJson(
      jsonDecode(response.body),
    );
  } else {
    throw Exception('faild');
  }
}

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code image. also share your response data

Comment: Only English please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Reason :
You are getting null in response so the cast is not working . you need to check the response is null or not if not null then do cast .
Example :

```
var response = await http.get("Your URL");
if(response != null && response.code == 200){
--- here you neeed to do your staff 
}
```

//handle the null